# Why does printing a structure variable give the value of the first element?

Tags: c

Consider this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct s{
  int i;
} C;

int main(){
  C.i=8;
  printf("%u %u",C,C.i);
}
```

Output:

```
8  8
```

Why does printing C give the value of the first element?

Comment: How do you think the variables in the structure are laid out? Normally one after the other. The may be some padding/alignment to optimise memory access, it's up to the compiler. Try printing out `&C` and the address of its attributes `&C.i`, `&C.j`, etc :)

Comment: True, the first member of the struct is also the beginning of the stuct itself hence printing the content of the struct gives back the content of its first member.

Comment: my question is why does printing C gives me value of first element. I know how struct variables is laid in memory,but I don't know why printing C is giving me first element

Comment: can i think structure variable as an alias for the memory location of first element.

Comment: "C" is just a syntactic sugar. A struct simply allows you to pass along and process multiple memory blocks without the need to do that manually for each one of those.

Comment: in other words: what is the value of `C`? Its address? Its first attribute?

Comment: if I print C i am getting value as 8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not depend on it in any way, since it is *undefined behavior*. The `%u` format specifier expects an expression of type `unsigned int`, while you are passing a `struct C`. For `int` type use either `%d` or `%i`.

The result is `8`, as structs, like any other objects are passed by value. It has only one member, thus it's likely, that it has the same size, as object of `int` type. In other words:

```
sizeof(int) == sizeof(struct C)
```

holds. The `printf()` function interprets struct object as `unsigned int`, hence you get the same number.

Comment: True about the undefined behaviour. Also in C++ (not C) using std::cout will issue a direct error and compilation will fail. You actually should get a warning message from your compiler if the -Wformat flag is set: `warning: format '%u' expects argument of type 'unsigned int', but argument 2 has type 's' [-Wformat]`

Comment: what happens if I declare int and char in structure. sizeof(int)<sizeof(struct c)

Comment: @user5174296: It may be even worse, since sizes are different. Most likely it would broke displaying subsequent arguments. Don't do this.

Comment: that's true. I have just tried adding another attribute `float f; int i;`. Then `C.f=3.0; C.i=8; printf("%f, %f, %d", C, C.f, C.i);` outputs `3.000000, 0.000000, 1077936128`